# trello responds "invalid key", when trying to delete card's label but there is nothing wrong with the key

Tags: node.js, api, trello

I am trying to delete a card's label on trello and am getting "invalid key" as response from trello api.

my apikey, token, card ID and labelID are correct I have checked against their documentation, where you can input these and try.

my code is the same as on their documentation:

```
var optionsDeleteLabel = {
      method: 'DELETE',
      url: `https://api.trello.com/1/cards/${body[i].id}/idLabels/${greenLabelId}&key=${apiKey}&token=${token}`,
    };
    request(optionsDeleteLabel, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);

      console.log(body);
    });
```

what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Try to avoid to use the backtick on the string, because that is ES6 syntax and maybe your Nodejs version doesn't support it yet. In any case, check the request that you're actually sending to the Trello API and verify the string is formatted as expected.

Comment: My Nodejs version is definitely supporting this syntax, most of my code (other functions) are already using it. However I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: Yes it turned out that the URI string, being generated was wrong... However not using the backtick did't do it...  Thank you!

Comment: If you add an answer about what was happening and how you solved that, this question could be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everybody, for the comments on my question.

Indeed I have found the problem and the solution. When I was getting the body[i].id , it was not getting parsed correctly (I was using JSON.stringfy and it was giving me with quotes), resulting in URL of the request being incorrect (the card ID in the URL had quotes). Trello was responding invalid key because the URL was not referring to the resource I was trying to reach, but to another...

the solution was to use

```
JSON.stringify(body[i].id).replace(/\"/g, "")
```

to get a new variable which I have used to make the URL without the quotes before and after the card id